# How to set up an extra constraint for 1-to-many relationship without using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, check-constraints

I have come across a database in my current position that needs allot of TLC to say the least, there are many cross reference tables all having the same structure schema wise, and all using triggers to enforce business logic, or domain integrity it would seem. I am trying to figure out if I can replace some of the triggers with constraints. Below is a typical table definition meeting this pattern. There are about 400 of these tables that exist all using the same trigger based solution.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FooXRef
(
FooXRefID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BarID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [fk_Bar] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Bar(BarID),
DefaultRecord BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FooXRef_Default] DEFAULT(1)
);
```

The rule being there can exist infinite number of records with the same value in `BarID` and `DefaultRecord = 0`, but only a single record can exist where `BarID` is in the table and `DefaultRecord = 1`.

What type of constraint would I need to setup to allow for that combination?

This table structure and trigger to enforce this combination is 400 in the current database, and in the next one I am undertaking in the thousands. Is it simply not possible to setup a constraint that would work for this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, based on the example, you must maintain that programmatically.

Comment: Does the example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) give you any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible variant without using a trigger.

Create a filtered unique index on `(BarID, DefaultRecord)` with the filter condition `WHERE ([DefaultRecord]=(1))`.

With such index in place you can insert only one row per `BarID` that has `DefaultRecord = 1`.

It is possible to have zero number of rows that have `DefaultRecord = 1`.

It is possible to have any number of rows that have `DefaultRecord = 0`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DefaultRecord] ON [dbo].[FooXRef]
(
    [BarID] ASC,
    [DefaultRecord] ASC
)
WHERE ([DefaultRecord]=(1))
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to have 0 rows that have Default record = 1. Yes it is also possible to have any number of rows where default record = 0. I will try to apply your suggestion and see where i get.

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you very much. I didn't even think of a unique index as opposed to a check constraint.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you found this answer useful. I edited the title of the question and tried to make it more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for making the edits as well, I am sure others have run into this issue. I have largely replaced the first database with this solution, and not only did full regression application testing succeed but I also got some small performance gains. Fantastic solution!!